# Wrapping of Application Settings in a Web Application

Tags: .net, configuration, web-config

I have this application setting in my Web.Config of an ASP.NET MVC 4 project.

```
  <appSettings>
        ...
    <add key="GridSize" value="12" />
  </appSettings>
```

I only use it in one place like this

```
int gridSize = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GridSize"]);
```

If I ever wanted to use this in more places throughout my code, what is the recommended approach?

Is it worth having a wrapper for this so the integer parsing is only done in one place for example?

Just trying to get some examples of what the general approach is for things like this.

Thanks

Comment: AppSettings doesn't maps to the applicationSettings section. Something is not right in your example

Comment: @Steve yup your right, I noticed that after I posted it. I will updated it shortly :-) the question still stands hopefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before giving my answer, I wish to remember that the recommended way to work with app.config is through the `applicationSettings` and `userSettings` sections. These sections allows to store and retrieve configuration properties without the problem of string conversion to a specific datatype.
Your example, if stored in the applicationSettings with SerializeAs="Integer" the GridSize config could be read back with

```
int size = Properties.Settings.Default.GridSize; //no conversion needed here
```

However, if you still want to use the *obsolete* `appSettings` section then I recommend to create a static ConfigurationUtility class that contains the values of your configuration and where you could centralize the Handling of these values (including Save and Load operations)

```
public static class ConfigurationUtility
{
      private static int _gridSize = -1;  // default for not initialized

      public static int GridSize
      {
          get
          {
              if(_gridSize == -1)
                  _gridSize = Int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GridSize"])
              return _gridSize;
          }
      }
}
```

This is just an example, more robust code will be required to handle situations like missing keys  invalid values for the expected datatype of the key

Comment: I was originally using a `setting.Settings` file which allowed me to do what you are suggesting above with `Properties.Settings.Default.GridSize`. I was told by a colleague not to use this for their web applications because it adds an extra layer of obscurity. However I still see it as a benefit over using the `ConfigurationManager`? Should this be used for a `ConnectionString` for example? Thanks for your example and showing that the other option would be to write your own `ConfigurationUtility` class.

Comment: if you really want to delve into this topic I suggest you read [these serie of articles](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16466/Unraveling-the-Mysteries-of-NET-2-0-Configuration)